# AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder cannot resolve method "withCredentials"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sts-securitytokenservice

Follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/AuthUsingTempSessionToken.html,
but encountered error

```
Cannot resolve method 'withCredentials' in 'AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder'
```

```
AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                                                                                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                                                                                .withRegion(REGION)
                                                                                .build();
```

Tried change dependencies version but it didn't work.

Comment: Which versions of the SDK did you try?

Comment: Hi there please provide more details about your question~

Comment: Hi, I used this dependency: '<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.471</version>
        </dependency>'